# Designing a threadsafe queue that has RAII semantics

Tags: c++, concurrency, c++17, condition-variable

I am trying to make a thread safe queue in C++17 based on condition variables.

How do I correctly interrupt the `WaitAndPop()` method in the queue's destructor?

The problem is that user classes will be waiting on the `WaitAndPop()` call to return before they destruct, meaning that their member queue never destructs, meaning that the return never happens, and I have a deadlock.

Here is a simplified example that illustrates the problem:

```cpp
#include <condition_variable>
#include <future>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <queue>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;
using namespace chrono_literals;

class ThreadsafeQueue {
 private:
  condition_variable cv_;
  bool cancel_;
  mutex mut_;
  queue<int> queue_;

 public:
  ThreadsafeQueue() : cancel_(false){};

  ~ThreadsafeQueue() {
    // although this would stop the cv, it never runs.
    cancel_ = true;
    cv_.notify_all();
    scoped_lock<mutex> lk(mut_);
  }

  void Push(int x) {
    {
      scoped_lock<mutex> lk(mut_);
      queue_.push(x);
    }
    cv_.notify_all();
  }

  // returns true if successful
  bool WaitAndPop(int &out) {
    unique_lock<mutex> lk(mut_);
    cv_.wait(lk, [this]() { return cancel_ || ! queue_.empty(); });

    if (cancel_) return false;

    out = queue_.front();
    queue_.pop();

    return true;
  }
};

class MyClass {
 private:
  future<void> fill_fut_;
  future<void> serve_fut_;
  ThreadsafeQueue queue_;
  bool running_;

 public:
  MyClass() : running_(true) {
    fill_fut_ = async(launch::async, &MyClass::FillThread, this);
    serve_fut_ = async(launch::async, &MyClass::ServeThread, this);
  };

  ~MyClass() {
    running_ = false;
    fill_fut_.get();
    serve_fut_.get();  // this prevents the threadsafe queue from destructing,
                       // which
                       // prevents the serve thread from stopping.
  }

  void FillThread() {
    while (running_) {
      queue_.Push(rand() & 100);
      this_thread::sleep_for(200ms);
    }
  }

  void ServeThread() {
    while (running_) {
      int x;
      bool ok = queue_.WaitAndPop(x);  // this never returns because the queue
                                       // never destructs
      if (ok)
        cout << "popped: " << x << endl;  // prints five times
      else
        cout << "pop failed";  // does not reach here
    }
  }
};

int main() {
  MyClass obj;

  this_thread::sleep_for(1s);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This overall design is suboptimal, and your issue is the result of the suboptimal design, and the correct solution is to fix the design. These kinds of things should be based on reference-counted objects, `std::shared_ptr` and friends. If all of this was managed as a reference-counted object, an invocation of the destructor means that this is the last reference to the object, in the last thread that used it, there's no other thread that could possibly use it, so nothing that this destructor does is needed at all. The `cancel` flag can be completely eliminated. Much simpler, isn't it?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thanks for your input. I suppose my question is how to “fix the design”. I’m a little confused about your suggestion to use smart pointers - how would they help solve the problem of destructing a `wait`ing condition variable?

Comment: Because, by definition, it would only get destroyed when no other thread could possibly have the reference to the object in question, so why would need to wait for any other thread to be returning from `WaitAndPop`, when no other thread could possibly be calling `WaitAndPop`, because the only thread that has the last reference to the object is destroying it? A thread can't call `WaitAndPop` of the object unless it has a reference to it, someplace. And if this thread is destroying the last reference, then logic dictates that no other thread could possibly have it.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Maybe my example was too simplified from an actual use case. I've updated it to be closer to reality. Multiple threads *can* access the threadsafe queue object. But still, I don't see the use of smart pointers in this case - there aren't any pointers in my code. I would really appreciate it if you posted an example of your suggested tweaks as an answer to help me understand.

Comment: Where did I claim that multiple threads can't access? Of course they can. But, with an appropriate design, one can logically prove that when the destructor gets invoked, only one thread remains that has access to the object: the one that's destroying it. This is not a tweak. This is a complete redesign and a rewrite, that uses smart pointers.

Comment: Here's a Youtube video from javidx9 that is based on client-server network programming, and towards the end of the video he implements and explains this exact concept of a thread-safe queuing interface framework that both the client and server objects will use. It is very insightful, you might want to check it out. It's definitely worth the time! The video is about an hour long and is part one of a mini-series of videos. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2hNdkYInj4g